# Make subitem behave like a nested itemize

Tags: lists, itemize

Is it possible to make `\subitem` work like a nested itemize? For example, this is what I want the output to look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize} 

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \blindtext
    \end{itemize}

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \blindtext
    \end{itemize}   

\end{itemize}       
\end{document}
```

But can I achieve a similar layout using just `\subitem`? Specifically I need the lines following the first line of the subitem to be 'in-line' with the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize}

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor
    \subitem \blindtext

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor
    \subitem \blindtext

\end{itemize}       
\end{document}
```

My motivation for asking is because using just `\subitem` is quicker to type than doing a nested `\begin{itemize}`...`\end{itemize}`. And I have many bullet points in this style to type.

Comment: I cannot solve your question, but thanks for sharing us the `\subitem` command! I've never use that.

Comment: You could of course define `\subitem`  to do anything you want but the default definition isn't really related to `\item` from `itemize` it is not defined in core latex it is defined in `article` class as part of its support for indices, this is generated by `makeindex` for subitems (and similarly for subsubitems) in an index.

Comment: your question is actually rather confusing as your example image looks like a simple non-nested itemize, although you have used a nested one-item itemize in the markup you are using `\item[]` so there is no label so essentially it is doing nothing. Do you need a nested list at all, or are you just wanting to style the text in the main list?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right, I actually just want a paragraph to proceed an item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see there are no nested lists here, just a specification of the paragraph shape for paragraphs within an item, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document} 

  \begin{itemize}[itemindent=-2em,leftmargin=2em]

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor

     \blindtext

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor

    \blindtext

   \end{itemize} 

\end{document}
```

---

To answer the question in the title, you could of course define `\subitem` to do anything you want, but the default definition isn't really related to `\item` from `itemize` Unlike `\item`, it is not defined in core latex; it is defined in `article` class as part of its support for indices, this is generated by `makeindex` for subitems (and similarly for subsubitems) in an index.